# Set php version for specific virtualhost Centos7/Apache

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have been installed php7 on Centos7/Apache (http://kho.ltdvietnam.com/info.php)
Now I want to install and run php5.6 on specific virtualhost since that source code only can run on PHP 5.6. Could you tell me how:
1. Install php5.6 beside my current php7
2. Setup php5.6 on specific virtualhost
Thanks for you advanced!

Comment: you better install both versions in CentOs but you can run only one version at a time.I did the same for Ubuntu 16 as my some projects run only either of the version only.If you really want like that I can give details as answer.